# Can Google Container Registry (gcr) support Docker Image Manifest V 2, Schema 1?

Tags: google-container-registry

From https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/image-formats, I see gcr supports Docker Image Manifest V 2, Schema 1. However when I try to get the schema 1 manifest for an image (`gcr.io/google-containers/busybox`) via `curl`, it failed:

> Unexpected HTTP response '404 Not Found' when trying to get the schema 1 manifest

So I am confused if gcr really support it or not.

Answer (score 1):

What's your actual `curl` command?

Try

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws" https://gcr.io/v2/google-containers/busybox/manifests/latest
```

Comment: OK, I know the difference now. The header I specified in my curl command is `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json`, if I change it to `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws`, then it works. So the question turns to why the former header was deprecated by gcr, based on Docker's doc (https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-1/), both of them should be supported.